# Django get_query_set override is being cached

Tags: python, django, filter, dry, django-queryset

I'm overriding Django's get_query_set function on one of my models dynamically. I'm doing this to forcibly filter the original query set returned by Model.objects.all/filter/get by a "scenario" value, using a decorator. Here's the decorator's function:

```
# Get the base QuerySet for these models before we modify their
# QuerySet managers. This prevents infinite recursion since the
# get_query_set function doesn't rely on itself to get this base QuerySet.
all_income_objects = Income.objects.all()

# Figure out what scenario the user is using.
current_scenario = Scenario.objects.get(user=request.user, selected=True)

# Modify the imported income class to filter based on the current scenario.
Expense.objects.get_query_set = lambda: all_expense_objects.filter(scenario=current_scenario)

# Call the method that was initially supposed to
# be executed before we were so rudely interrupted.
return view(request, **arguments)
```

I'm doing this to DRY up the code, so that all of my queries aren't littered with an additional filter. However, if the scenario changes, no objects are being returned. If I kill all of my python processes on my server, the objects for the newly select scenario appear. I'm thinking that it's caching the modified class, and then when the scenario changes, it's applying another filter that will never make sense, since objects can only have one scenario at a time.

This hasn't been an issue with user-based filters because the user never changes for my session. Is passenger doing something stupid to hold onto class objects between requests? Should I be bailing on this weird design pattern and just implement these filters on a per-view basis? There must be a best practice for DRYing filters up that apply across many views based on something dynamic, like the current user.

Comment: I don't see where the decorator is?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a Manager object for the model which takes the user as an argument where this filtering is done.  My understanding of being DRY w/ Django querysets is to use a Model Manager

```
#### view code:
def some_view(request):
    expenses = Expense.objects.filter_by_cur_scenario(request.user)

    # add additional filters here, or add to manager via more params
    expenses = expenses.filter(something_else=True)

#### models code:
class ExpenseManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_cur_scenario(self, user):
        current_scenario = Scenario.objects.get(user=request.user, selected=True)
        return self.filter(scenario=current_scenario)

class Expense(models.Model):
    objects = ExpenseManager()
```

Also, one quick caveat on the manager (which may apply to overriding get_query_set): foreign relationships will not take into account any filtering done at this level. For example, you override the MyObject.objects.filter() method to always filter out deleted rows; A model w/ a foreignkey to that won't use that filter function (at least from what I understand -- someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to have this implementation happen without having to code anything in other views. Essentially, after the class is imported, I want to modify it so that no matter where it's referenced using Expense.objects.get/filter/all it's already been filtered. As a result, there is no implementation required for any of the other views; it's completely transparent. And, even in cases where I'm using it as a ForeignKey, when an object is retrieved using the aforementioned Expense.objects.get/filter/all, they'll be filtered as well.